# How To Change Currency Code Using Quote ID

Tags: magento2, rest-api, currency, multicurrency

I need to change the quote currency to order from the mobile app. For this, I send the quote id from the mobile app, I did the following code on Magento, but it did not work. Suggest me the correct way to change the currency code

```
$quote = $this->quoteFactory->create()->load(627);
$quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode('USD');
$quote->save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
$quote->setBaseCurrencyCode('USD');
$quote->setGlobalCurrencyCode('USD');
$quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode('USD');
$quote->setStoreCurrencyCode('USD');
$quote->save();
```

Note: Code is not tested but hopes it will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
 /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\Currency $quoteCurrency */
                $quoteCurrency = $this->quoteCurrencyFactory->create()
                    ->setGlobalCurrencyCode(""GBP"")
                    ->setBaseCurrencyCode(""GBP"")
                    ->setStoreCurrencyCode(""GBP"")
                    ->setQuoteCurrencyCode(""GBP"")
                    ->setStoreToBaseRate(1.00)
                    ->setStoreToQuoteRate(1.00)
                    ->setBaseToGlobalRate(1.00)
                    ->setBaseToQuoteRate(1.00);
    
    /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
                $quote = $this->cartRepositoryInterface->get($cartId);
                $quote->setStore($store);
    
                // forcefully changing the currency for quote
                $quote->setForcedCurrency($directoryCurrency);
                $quote->setBaseCurrencyCode(""GBP"");
                $quote->setGlobalCurrencyCode(""GBP"");
                $quote->setStoreCurrencyCode(""GBP"");
                $quote->setQuoteCurrencyCode(""GBP"");
                $quote->setCurrency($quoteCurrency);
                $quote->save();
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use quote Model

```
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->load($shoppingcartid);
```

Then Set Currency

```
$quote->setCurrency('GBP');
```

Comment: The tag of this question is magento2, you are providing code for magento 1